# Failed to fetch error: Tried everything from changing Server to changing /etc/resolv.config and /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: 16.04, server, apt, updates

I have been running Ubuntu 16.04 for the last 4-5 months however, from yesterday I'm facing this problem.

When I try to update or upgrade my system using:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get this as the result:

```
    Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 winehq-devel amd64 1.9.23~ubuntu16.04.1
      Could not connect to 213.112.147.72:14552 (213.112.147.72), connection timed out
    Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 wine-devel amd64 1.9.23~ubuntu16.04.1
      Unable to connect to 213.112.147.72:14552:
    Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 wine-devel-amd64 amd64 1.9.23~ubuntu16.04.1
      Unable to connect to 213.112.147.72:14552:
    Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main i386 wine-devel-i386 i386 1.9.23~ubuntu16.04.1
      Unable to connect to 213.112.147.72:14552:
    Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main i386 papirus-gtk-icon-theme all 2016.11.10ubuntu16.04
      Unable to connect to 213.112.147.72:14552:
    Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main i386 papirus-gtk-icon-theme all 2016.11.10ubuntu16.04
      Unable to connect to 213.112.147.72:14552:
    E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine-devel/winehq-devel_1.9.23~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to 213.112.147.72:14552 (213.112.147.72), connection timed out

    E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine-devel/wine-devel_1.9.23~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 213.112.147.72:14552:

    E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine-devel/wine-devel-amd64_1.9.23~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 213.112.147.72:14552:

    E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine-devel/wine-devel-i386_1.9.23~ubuntu16.04.1_i386.deb  Unable to connect to 213.112.147.72:14552:

    E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu/pool/main/p/papirus-gtk-icon-theme/papirus-gtk-icon-theme_2016.11.10ubuntu16.04_all.deb  Unable to connect to 213.112.147.72:14552:

    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How do I fix this? I've really tried everything as mentioned.

**Note:** I've changed my source server in an attempt to get it working

Result of `host ppa.launchpad.net`:

```
ppa.launchpad.net has address 91.189.95.83
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

`grep -i wine /etc/apt/sources.list` returned nothing

Result of `grep -i wine /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` :

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-ubuntu-wine-builds-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-ubuntu-wine-builds-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial main
```

Result of `ping ppa.launchpad.net`:

```
PING ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=204 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=228 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=252 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=173 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=140 ms
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=220 ms
```

Result of `ping 91.189.95.83`:

```
64 bytes from 91.189.95.83: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=171 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.95.83: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=194 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.95.83: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=140 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.95.83: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=239 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.95.83: icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=139 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.95.83: icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=155 ms
```

Turning off the router, modem and Ubuntu then turning them back on have similar results.

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

`sudo lshw -C network`:

```
[sudo] password for arghhjayy: 
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 83
       serial: 2c:6e:85:20:60:b1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-45-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=10.0.0.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:50 memory:aa200000-aa201fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: 20:47:47:58:c1:c0
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:aa100000-aa100fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff
```

I'm running on wireless.

Comment: In `terminal`, show us the output of `host ppa.launchpad.net`, and `ping ppa.launchpad.net`, and `grep -i wine /etc/apt/sources.list`, and `grep -i wine /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. ps: **Don't** manually edit /etc/resolv.conf, and set your server to US.

Comment: I've edited the question details and added all the information you asked for. Also, changed my server to US.

Comment: **Thanks!** Looks like we have an Internet connection problem. Show me the output of `ping ppa.launchpad.net` and `ping 91.189.95.83`. Then... **shutdown** Ubuntu, and **power off** your router and your dsl/cable modem. Then, in this **exact** order... power on your dsl/cable modem, wait 60 seconds, power on your router, wait 60 seconds, restart Ubuntu. Then see if the 2 ping commands now work.

Comment: I've updated the question description.

Comment: Hum, that didn't fail the way I thought it would. Maybe your Internet connection problem is intermittent, or it fixed itself. Try the `sudo apt-get update` command again and see if it works now. Then show me the results of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, and `sudo lshw -C network`. Are you running with wireless, or a wired connection?

Comment: Added,  though I tried to change the DNS to 8.8.8.8 before.

Comment: Go to `System Settings/Network`, scroll down the list in the left pane, select Network proxy. Make sure it's set to `none`, and click `Apply system wide`. In `terminal` type `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`. Go to `Network` panel icon and select `Edit connections`. Select your wireless profile, IPv4 tab, change popup from DHCP to `DHCP addresses only`, then put `208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220` in the DNS server field, click ok. One of these HAS to fix this problem.

Comment: This hurts, tried all but **nothing** worked! Is there any way we can change `apt`'s state to what it was a month ago or so? Like I'm getting problems only when I use `apt`. When I use `apt-get install`, it shoots an error but `pip install <package>` works!.  `pip` and `wget` are working fine. Is there any chance that something is wrong with `apt` and not with the network settings?

Comment: I'm tapped out too. Maybe another expert can chime in. It looks like your DNS is picking up the wrong address for ppa.launchpad.net. You could temporarily disable the two wine repositories in `Software & Updates` other software tab, and that should take care of the error, but then you won't get wine updates.... for now.

Comment: ps: you haven't edited/changed your `/etc/hosts` file, have you? Added ppa.launchpad.net in there?

Comment: THAT. ACTUALLY. WORKED!! I unchecked the wine ppa from `Software & Updates` and tried again, and it is working now! I almost gave in, was gonna install Fedora! Thank you very much @heynnema for all your responses. You're a cool guy. It feels so good to see `apt` back in action! Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Thanks for the update! Now... your homework is to figure out what's wrong with the wine repository. I'd just delete it altogether, and then re-add it, to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Hey, I can't connect to 91.189.95.83 too...

Comment: Hey @Elric, just uncheck unnecessary repositories from your "Software and Updates" application. It worked for me.